# PHP shell_exec get file

Tags: php, shell-exec

Is there any way to get file contents of external webiste, say [https://www.example.com/](https://www.example.com).
For eg. Using Python from shell_exec. I tried python but got blank.

Comment: Are you trying to scrape the source files from a remote webserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want to use shell_exec but
you can use

```
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/');
```

or

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

if you want to maintain the session you could use curl with CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE
eg:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiefile");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookiefile");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name() . '=' . session_id());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.example.com/');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

or if you really want to use the shell_exec the use follwing

```
$data = shell_exec('curl -I https://www.example.com/');
echo "<pre>$data</pre>";
```

however for above to work you have to have curl installed check following for instillation of curl
https://curl.se/

hope this works

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot.